# Column "zone_id" does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, dapper, npgsql

Function in the PostgreSQL includes

[image: This function is present in the db]

When I am running through the query it is working fine like

```
Select * rpt.cst_data_integration_individuals(13, '2017-12-27T13:07:58Z', '2018-12-27T13:07:58Z', TRUE);
```

It is giving results.

But when I am trying through ADO.net, it is giving error like "zone_id" does not exists,

[image: Ado.net code for fetching the data from PostgresSql]

childrenQuery = "Select * from rpt.cst_data_integration_individuals(zone_id, period_start, period_end, is_child)";

Please someone help me.

Comment: zoneId variable - what is it's value?

Comment: @Andrew The value for zoneId is 13,an integer which it should take.

Comment: I tried this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481752/7276188 with Dapper but getting the same error. Is there something I am missing. I used for functions but. And that function I am trying to execute through query as childrenQuery

Comment: `Select * from rpt.cst_data_integration_individuals(zone_id, period_start, period_end, is_child` You are missing `@` before `zone_id` and the other parameters. `(@zone_id, @period_start` This is a simple typo, thus I'd recommend people vote to close this question.

Comment: After adding the @ infront of that, I am getting error "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: That is a new question. Please write a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
Select * from rpt.cst_data_integration_individuals(zone_id, period_start, period_end, is_child)
```

Implies that zone_id, etc are fields available.  If this were within a stored procedure and those were variables, it would likely work, but as it stands in your query it doesn't even make sense.

You need to invoke parameters in your actual `childrenQuery` with either the ':' or the '@' character.

```
Select * from rpt.cst_data_integration_individuals(:zone_id, :period_start, :period_end, :is_child)
```

Also, to help with debugging, declare your parameters explicitly with datatypes.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("zone_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("period_start", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("period_end", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("is_child", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Boolean));

cmd.Parameters[0].Value = zoneId;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = fromDate;
cmd.Parameters[2].Value = toDate;
cmd.Parameters[3].Value = true;
```

(There are golfed versions of the above, but I never bother -- I like the readabilty)

If you are using earlier version of Npgsql, they will probably be forgiving.  If you are using recent version, they will give you a pretty clear error of where you went wrong.  If `zoneId` is an integer (and `true` obviously matches a boolean datatype), then my **guess** would be there was a mismatch with how .NET sent the `DateTime` datatype -- maybe it assumed it was a timestamp without time zone.

Either way, the explicit parameter declarations will help, whereas `AddWithValue` is basically asking it to take its best guess.

Maybe for the time being avoid `AddWithValue`.  I'm not going to lie, I use it from time to time, but you really shoud limit its use.