# Dapper - Null values are being inserted into MySql table

Tags: mysql, dapper

After hours of trying to figure out the problem, I am still stuck. Here is the problem:

I have a MySql query in my C# code:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS(Salutation, FirstName, LastName) VALUES(?salutation, ?firstName, ?lastName)";
```

This query is in a method which accepts an ExpandoObject:

```
public async Task AddMember(ExpandoObject expando)
{
    var sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS(Salutation, FirstName, LastName) VALUES(?salutation, ?firstName, ?lastName)";

    // Convert the incoming ExpandoObject to Dapper's DynamicParameters
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481678/how-to-create-arguments-for-a-dapper-query-dynamically
    if (expando != null)
    {
        var dbArgs = new DynamicParameters();

        foreach (var param in expando)
        {
            dbArgs.Add(param.Key, param.Value);
        }

        await mySqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(sql, dbArgs);
    }
}
```

The query is executing (meaning that I am not getting an error, and a row is created in the Members table, and also the MemberId column value is generated), but Salutation, FirstName and LastName are null.

I checked the contents of the Expando. The input values are all there.

I tried various things.

- Using @ and : instead of ? in the query.
- Using the Expando directly in QueryAsync instead of converting it to DynamicParameters.
- Using an IDictionary as the input instead of the ExpandoObject and passing it directly to QueryAsync.
- Using QueryAsync instead of ExecuteAsync.

Nothing works. The 3 columns are null every time. Not sure what is wrong here.

Due to several reasons, I can't use a strong type like Member as the input to this method. I have to use 
an ExpandoObject.

- The MySql version I'm using is 5.7.13
- My Dapper version is 1.60.6
- The MySql.Data nuget package that I'm using is 8.0.17

Comment: Can you confirm that the values in `param.Key` match exactly the params in your sql: `salutation`, `firstName`, `firstName`. Also, I always prefix mine with `@`, not `?`. You also don't need to use the `@/?` in your `param.Key` value.

Comment: @scgough, I confirmed that each param.key matches the params in the SQL. And yes, in the query, I did prefix the params with @. In fact, I tried using ? after using @ didn't work.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, try bypassing the expando with hard-codes values instead and see if that works. Also, silly question I know but has the param.Value got a value.

Comment: Yes, it works with  hard-coded values, and I also confirmed that param.Value is assigned correctly.

Comment: It works when I use a MySqlCommand object directly and set its CommandText to the sql value.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Maybe it’s because Dapper can’t correctly determine the value types from the DynamicParameters?

Comment: I too think so.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm basing this on the theory that we discussed above. I'd expand on your `DynamicParameters` so you are passing in `DBType` values as well.

For example: (source: https://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-dynamic)

```
parameter.Add("@Kind", InvoiceKind.WebInvoice, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameter.Add("@Code", "Many_Insert_0", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameter.Add("@RowCount", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

So, in your case it could be something like:

```
public async Task AddMember(ExpandoObject expando)
{
    var sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS(Salutation, FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@salutation, @firstName, @lastName)";

    // Convert the incoming ExpandoObject to Dapper's DynamicParameters
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481678/how-to-create-arguments-for-a-dapper-query-dynamically
    if (expando != null)
    {
        var dbArgs = new DynamicParameters();

        foreach (var param in expando)
        {
            dbArgs.Add(param.Key, param.Value, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
        }

        await mySqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(sql, dbArgs);
    }
}
```

I get this detracts a little from the dynamic way you're trying to do this (by having the type and direction hard-coded) but you could add to your initial Expando to allow for this value to be set and passed in to the `AddMember` method.